# AWS RDS: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-iam

I know this question has been raised a couple of times, but the suggestions proposed aren't working for me. So here's a bit of context on what I'm trying to do.

I have an RDS MySQL Database that I'm trying to access programatically using an IAM role from an EMR cluster. I'm able to login to the Database as root user without any issues, post which I did the following

1. Logged into the DB as admin and then created a user

   `create user my_user identified with AWSAuthenticationPlugin as 'RDS'`.
2. `grant usage on db_name.* to 'my_user'@'%'require ssl;`
3. The IAM role attached to the EMR instance has the following properties,

- Has an AWS managed policy "AmazonRDSDataFullAccess"
- An inline policy

  ```
   {
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
       {
           "Effect": "Allow",
           "Action": [
               "rds-db:connect"
           ],
           "Resource": [
               "arn:aws:rds-db:<region>:<account_id>:dbuser:<db_resource_id>/my_user"
           ]
       }
   ]
  ```

  }

4. The Security group attached with the DB permits MySQL/Aurora access from EMR cluster security group

I access the DB programatically in a similar manner as stated in [Connecting to DB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Java.html) section.

The stack trace I get is:

```
User class threw exception: java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'my_user'@'host' (using password: YES)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:963)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3966)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3902)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:875)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1712)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1228)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2253)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2284)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2083)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:806)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:410)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:328)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
```

I've tried a lot to debug what could be the possible reason for the error but I'm not able to find any reason, Appreciate if someone could help me out on this. I'm more than willing to elaborate on any step here (being my first post I might have not written it properly). Thanks in advance

UPD 1: I also tried accessing the user with help of mysql CLI, through the following command.

```
TOKEN="$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname $RDSHOST --port 3306 --region us-east-1 --username my_user)" 
mysql --host=$RDSHOST --port=3306 --ssl-ca=rds-ca-2019-root.pem --user=my_user --password=$TOKEN
```

This also gives a similar message `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'my_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

UPD 2: I suspect that there might be a mistake in the way I create the user in the DB as the error still persists even after changing the Resource to `*`. Could someone have a closer look here.

Comment: Is the database an Aurora Serverless DB or just a regular RDS MySQL or Aurora database? Have you enabled IAM authentication for DB connections in the RDS server settings?

Comment: It is a mySQL database and I have enables IAM authentication in RDS server settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was attaching the policies to the EMR role, I had to attach it to the EC2 instance profile of the EMR cluster

Answer (score 0):

The `AmazonRDSDataFullAccess` policy is for interacting with the serverless RDS data API. It does not provide the appropriate permissions for performing a standard DB connection with IAM authentication. You need to follow the guide [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.IAMPolicy.html) to create the appropriate policy. In particular you need to give the EC2 instance profile the `rds-db:connect` permission.

Comment: I had the same policy attached to the role as well. Do you spot any other stuff which looks wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you change the resource in the inline policy to just `*`? That test would eliminate any possible errors you have in the resource ARN.

Comment: The same error still persists   
```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "rds-db:connect"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the policy I used

Answer (score 0):

You may try following:

1. Try to recreate the DB user and giving it grants again
2. Instead of inline policy, try with Customer Managed Policy till connection issue is resolved
3. There is a comma after the resource ARN in the inline policy, remove that as well.

Comment: 1. I tried recreating the DB but I saw the same error.
2. I changed this but the error still persists.
3. This was a mistake done while pasting it out here, I've edited the question.

Comment: Are you getting anything back from => `TOKEN="$(aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname $RDSHOST --port 3306 --region us-east-1 --username my_user)"` ?

Comment: Yes the token is being generated

Comment: Try this: add `--enable-cleartext-plugin` before `--user` when you connect to mysql from CLI

Comment: I tried this and I got an error saying ```mysql: unknown option '--enable-cleartext-plugin'```

Comment: Strange.. as per the documentation [Connecting to Your DB Instance Using IAM Authentication from the Command Line: AWS CLI and mysql Client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.AWSCLI.html#UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.AWSCLI.AuthToken), it should be an acceptable option. What is the version on MySQL engine? Also ensure that you have provided correct/full path for SSL cert.

Comment: MySQL engine: `5.7.26`. SSL cert I'm using is `rds-ca-2019-us-east-1.pem`, do you find anything wrong?

Comment: I looked this up https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cleartext-pluggable-authentication.html and it says that you need to set this env variable `LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN` but I don't find any resource to figure out how to set this.

Comment: I tried to recreate this issue but couldn't - I was able to connect without any issues. Try updating the [MySql client](https://gist.github.com/sshymko/63ee4e9bc685c59a6ff548f1573b9c74) you're using on your EC2. Also try elevating GRANT for db user "my_user" to `grant usage on *.* to 'my_user'@'%'require ssl;`